# How can I change the Q Webserver to stop restricting the number of displayed rows/items

Tags: kdb

The Q Webserver per default returns a limited view of n rows and has the option to scroll (up/down/start/end). Is there any way where I can remove that restriction and display the whole table/list/dict? Or at least increase n?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using \C with two arguments, eg. `\C 100 1000` (first for number of rows, second for number of columns) will adjust the console size to display more rows and columns. 2000 is the maximum limit for each dimension.
See the link below for further information too: 
https://code.kx.com/q/ref/cmdline/#-c-http-size

.z.ph might be more useful for you if you need to work around the limit. See: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotz/#zph-http-get

Customising the webserver is another option for modifying the output to the screen. See:
https://code.kx.com/q/cookbook/custom-web/